# php with mysql: import .csv delimited space

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import, insert

How import this file to mysql with spaces between rows?
Through phpmyadmin it is possible, but I need do it via website.

```
<?php
// Check if file was uploaded & there were no errors
if ($_FILES && $_FILES['csv-file']['error'] == 0) {
    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['csv-file']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if extension is csv then proceed to import
    if($extension == 'csv'){
        // Open file for reading
        $file = fopen($_FILES['csv-file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
        // Loop through all rows of file and insert them to database table
        while (!feof($file)) {
            // Get current row as recordset
            $row = fgetcsv($file);
            if (!empty($row)) {
                $data = [];
                $data['numbers'] = htmlentities($row[0]);
                $data['tids'] = htmlentities($row[1]);
                $data['date'] = htmlentities($row[2]);
                $data['time'] = htmlentities($row[3]);
                $data['zero'] = htmlentities($row[4]);
                $data['terminal_sn'] = htmlentities($row[5]);
                $data['space'] = htmlentities($row[6]);
                $records[] = $data;
                mysqli_query($dbcon,"INSERT INTO employees (".implode(",",array_keys($data)).") VALUES ('".implode("','",array_values($data))."')");
            }
        }
    }else{?>
```

And this is my .csv file with data:

```
10222157120501 T0040922 07/09/2020 18:13:56 0 315-525-348 1
10223157120502 T0040923 07/09/2020 18:15:24 0 318-027-497 1
10224157120503 T0040924 07/09/2020 18:15:36 0 316-176-614 1
10225157120504 T0040925 07/09/2020 18:16:25 0 317-377-077 1
```

Comment: Spaces between rows? Do you mean the `csv` has a blank row every other row?

Comment: If the space is between fields, look at the manual for `fgetcsv()` for the delimiter.

Comment: Ahh that makes more sense @NigelRen :) Maybe its time to go and watch University Challenge instead

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, This is output file that I need imported into the database.
This will only be used within the organization on localhost.

Comment: The [`fgetcsv()` Manual Page, look at parameter 3 :)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) Also look at the examples for a better read and loop methid

Comment: `htmlentities` should only be being used when outputting to an HTML doc.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code. Additionally the procedural interface has less rigorous error checking and reporting, frustrating debugging efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// prepare the insert query once outside the loop
$sql = 'INSERT INTO employees (`numbers`, `tids`, `date`, `time`, 
                               `zero`, `terminal_sn`, `space`)
            VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare($sql);

if (($handle = fopen($_FILES['csv-file']['name'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, " ")) !== FALSE) {
        //             space delimiter      ^
        
        // bind the columns to the query parameters
        $stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3],
                                     $row[4],$row[5], row[6]);
        // execute the query with parameters replaced with data
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Also possible: `LOAD DATA INFILE` to directly import the CSV.

Comment: The date value in the csv field should be stored in a date data type (and presumably this is actually a date+time - so the 2 attributes from the CSV should be combined to a single value). But the above will probably not work as expected in such a scenario. really the values need to parsed and vonverted to an appropriate representation.

Comment: @symcbean Totally agree, was going to wait for a complaint that this did not work before making that point, but none came. I am assuming that means the date and time are being stored as a VARCHAR data type columns. We will wait for the SQL based question about how to do interesting stuff with dates that are not stored in a DATE data type :)